# What is synaptic clearance?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, terminology, neurotransmitter, synapses

Please explain what the term **synaptic clearance** means. For example, what would dopamine synaptic clearance be? It is important to me in context of dopamine signaling variation due to difference in synaptic clearence level.

Some gene alleles are associated with greater synaptic clearance in dopamine pathways. It used to explain dopamine level variation and throught it some brain areas activity (for example Nucleus Accumbens) difference among people with different genotypes. For more information [see for example](http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21593733). Also, reduced synaptic clearence [related to](http://nature.com/npp/journal/v22/n2/full/1395423a.html) greater dopamine signaling levels. So I was interested in this term from prespective of brain activity in areas with dopamine receptors

Comment: We generally appreciate if you provide some background and show some of your own research effort. Background means some details on where you encountered this term. Background provides the context of the term  and helps in understanding its meaning (especially for not so popular terms). Research effort refers to any information that you were able to gather by searching the web or books.

Comment: Great.. Can you please add this to your question by editing it? Usually people would not go through the comments and secondly comments do not show up in searches. Finally, a question should be complete in itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Synaptic clearance" is referring to the clearing of a [neurotransmitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurotransmitter) from a [synaptic cleft](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Synaptic_cleft).  A [synapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synapse) is a place where one neuron can stimulate another neuron. The tiny gap between the neurons is called the synaptic cleft. The presynaptic (stimulating) neuron releases a neurotransmitter (such as [dopamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine)) into the cleft and some of the neurotransmitter is recognized by receptors in the membrane of the postsynaptic (stimulated) neuron.  In order for the synapse to stimulate the postsynaptic neuron a second time, the concentration of the neurotransmitter in the cleft must be reduced to its original levels.  This reduction is called clearance, and can occur in several ways (mainly dependent on the type of neurotransmitter).  The neurotransmitter may be transported back into the presynaptic neuron for reuse; this is called [reuptake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuptake).  The neurotransmitter may also be degraded (broken down chemically) into an inactive form.  To a lesser extent, neurotransmitter can also be absorbed by [astrocytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrocyte) or simply diffuse away out of the cleft.

Answer (score 1):

It means what it says: clearance of neurotransmitters from the synaptic cleft. In case of DA it's mediated by DA transporters. They are there to shorten the response of DA, making the synapse ready for another signaling cycle. It also regenerates DA in case the transporters are located in the presynaptic neuron.

<sub>**Reference**

[Ciliax, J *Neurosci* (1995); **75**(3): 1714-23](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/15/3/1714.full.pdf)</sub>